# Firefox - parent border effected by inner elements margins and padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, margin

I'm having an issue that's only present in Firefox (I'm using v28). Please see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/DgLTk/) for a visual explanation.

Basically, the content within `#header-wrap` is causing a 30px or so gap between the grey background of `#header-wrap` and it's RED bottom border. I've narrowed down the problem to `.jumbotron` having a bottom margin of 30px but I can't for the life of me figure out why it causes the gap between `#header-wrap`s background and it's border *only in firefox*.

> EDIT: I see that the fiddle version of my page is doing this in chrome as well. But the actual page is only doing it in firefox. Still, any help and explanation of this problem will be greatly appreciated.

I know I could fix this issue by removing the margin on `.jumbotron` but I can't in good conscience do that and move on without understanding why it only happens in firefox :)

Comment: I can't tell exactly which spacing you object to.  Could you edit the fiddle so the offending area is coloured red, or something, to make it more obvious? `.navbar`has a 20px bottom margin and `.jumbotron` has a 30 bottom margin, both are inside `#header-wrap`.  The gap between the bottom border of `#header-wrap` and its contents seems to be caused by `.jumbotron`'s margin directive.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the bottom border to red and updated the fiddle and question.

Comment: I see the 30px white space between the grey content and red border of jumbotron in Firefox and Chrome.  It's simply the margin directive.  Feel like I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD in good conscience remove the margin. I'm just saying that you SHOULD use a CSS reset. :) It only happens in firefox because it can read default h3 in this context with this behaviour

http://www.cssreset.com/

Example of CSS Reset

```
/**
* Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
* http://cssreset.com
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: does bootstrap not have a resset? I'm using bootstrap 3